# How to get a best appearance with PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been using PyQt for a time and I really like it. But now I feel the GUI I have been doing is not s modern-looking. This is a print of what I did so far:

[image]

So, I would like to know if is it possible to use effects, animations on pyqt. Where can I find some nice examples? I have been searching a lot for it.

I started to learn kivy, but as I use a lot of tables kivy is not prepared for that. Pyqt table widgets are very good.

Comment: You probably need to use QML to polish it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **QApplication::setStyle (QStyle style)** to set your desired graphical system. so you can try:

```
QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))
```

some options other than CleanLooks are:

- plastique
- cde
- motif
- sgi
- windows
- mac

Hope it helps!